# JSP output string with HTML?

Tags: html, string, jsp

I would like to output a string in a JSP page. The string contains
HTML tag.
How do I display the HTML version of the string in JSP?

e.g.

```
            `String str = "<b><u>bold and underlined</u></b>"`;
```

In JSP, I use `<%=str%>`

Instead of displaying the HTML version of the string (with bold and
underlining of the text), the above string is displayed. Can you help?

I also tried

```
                   <% out.print(str); %>
```

But didnt worked for me.

Comment: Deja vu: http://www.velocityreviews.com/forums/t136883-jsp-output-string-with-html-query.html (and from 2004, no less...)

Comment: Yeah I tried that but didnt work..Thats why I am questioning it here

Answer (score 16):

Better to use JSTL, something like:

```
<c:out value="${str}" escapeXml="false"/>
```

If `str` is coming in request then

```
<c:out value="${param.str}" escapeXml="false"/>
```

Here `escapeXml="false"` will instruct that html/xml tags should be evaluated and not escaped.

Comment: Thanks @Harry, Your escapeXml='false' tip helped me.

Answer (score 2):

don't know weather this helps..

By entering the string in the following manner allows you to show the code in a text area...

```
 String str = "<textarea><b><u>bold and underlined</u></b></textarea>";
```